# How to add "Last Updated Date" in line item in Excel?

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

In microsoft excel work sheet, I want a column with dates. These dates should be the date when anything in the line item is updated. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using vba code as below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Sheet2.Cells(Target.Row, 9).Value = Now()
End Sub
```

replace 9 by the column number where you want to update the date